# Recover Multibit Wallet on Mac

Tags: multibit

I had Multibit installed on my last mac computer around April 2013, that computer broke and I have had the hard drive recovered. I now have the files from that past Multibit on my new mac, including files named multi bit.wallet and multi bit-xxxxxxxxxx.wallet.

How do I go about recovering my bitcoin on my new computer?

Answer (score 2):

This should be the location of `wallet.dat` on `MAC`

```
~/Library/Application Support/MultiBit/
```

You will be able to copy this file to USB and paste it into the same location on your new MAC.

Answer (score 1):

Place the .wallet files on a secure USB drive, within Multibit there is an option to simply select location of a wallet file.

Im not sure what date exactly but they changed the format of the wallets. Multibit will automatically convert it to the new wallet format and bring up your old transactions.